# run application in the background IntentService

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I've developed an application that runs in the background and I used an `IntentService` for beginning.

This is my code:

```
public class UsbService extends IntentService {
    /** 
       * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
       * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
       */
      public UsbService() {

          super("UsbService");

      }



      /**
       * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
       * the intent that started the service. When this method returns, IntentService
       * stops the service, as appropriate.
       */

      @Override
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          Log.e("why", "fofo");
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "starting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    //  mNotification.notify(132, builder.build());
          // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
          // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
        /*  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000;
          while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
              synchronized (this) {
                  try {
                      wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                  }
              }
          }*/
      }
}
```

the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.servicesusb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app`enter code here`_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".UsbService"  >

            </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I want to start a service from a ADB shell so I used this command

```
am startservice -n com.example.servicesusb/.UsbService
```

... but the service don't start and I don't know the problem

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

if your service exists then it can be started as follows

**adb shell am startservice  <packageofservice>**

if still does not work try posting the error you received after you ran this command

Comment: there is no error but when i watch in paramte i dont find my srvice started

Comment: So heres a solution i think so.....You only have a service inside your package so when your package is installed noone is actually there to start that service , so starting it through adb is your only option then you will be able to see that service in phone Settings>Applications/Running ............Dont use / in package name as you'hv used above ...try just this   adb shell am startservice com.example.servicesusb.UsbService
 instead of com.example.servicesusb/.UsbService